# utf8 encoding in json rest api

Tags: api, json

i create a custom REST API to get posts

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'custom_api_get_all_posts' ); 



function custom_api_get_all_posts() {
    register_rest_route( 'custom/v1', '/all-posts', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'custom_api_get_all_posts_callback'
    ));
}

function custom_api_get_all_posts_callback( $request ) {
    // Initialize the array that will receive the posts' data. 
    $posts_data = array();
    // Receive and set the page parameter from the $request for pagination purposes
    $paged = $request->get_param( 'page' );
    $paged = ( isset( $paged ) || ! ( empty( $paged ) ) ) ? $paged : 1; 
    // Get the posts using the 'post' and 'news' post types
    $posts = get_posts( array(
            'paged' => $paged,
            'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
            'posts_per_page' => 10,            
            'post_type' => listing,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array (
                'taxonomy' => 'flux_rss',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'oui',
                )
            ), 
        )
    ); 


// Loop through the posts and push the desired data to the array we've initialized earlier in the form of an object
foreach( $posts as $post ) {

    $id = $post->ID; 
    $post_thumbnail = ( has_post_thumbnail( $id ) ) ? get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $id ) : null;

    $posts_data[] = (object) array( 
        'id' => $id, 
        'title' => $post->post_title,
        'excerpt' => wp_json_encode($post->post_excerpt), 
        'link' => $post->guid,
        'featured_img_src' => $post_thumbnail
    );
}                  
return $posts_data;
```

}

But i get some special character in the response so how i can transform json response to utf8

```
[{
    "id": 2087,
    "title": "Avec l\u2019ONPA",
    "excerpt": "\"Avec cette association cr\\u00e9\\u00e9e en 1971, les s\\u00e9niors de 55 ans et plus, en activit\\u00e9 professionnelle ou non, et vivant \\u00e0 domicile, m\\u00e8nent une vie active...\"",
    "link": "http:\/\/localhost\/focus\/?post_type=listing&#038;p=2087",
    "featured_img_src": "http:\/\/localhost\/focus\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/05\/avec-lonpa.jpg"
},
```

Comment: Some notes, your tax query could be replaced with `'flux_rss' => 'oui'`, and kudos for doing the smart thing and using terms instead of post meta, big performance gains :) But, `post__not_in` is very expensive, and you should use `WP_Query` as its default parameters are a little faster. Additionally, `listing` needs quotes around it, and you should set the `post_status` which will speed it up a little

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
'excerpt' => wp_json_encode($post->post_excerpt),
```

That array will get passed through `wp_json_encode` by the REST API, so it gets double encoded, so remove the `wp_json_encode` here, and it'll work out fine, it's just encoding, it's not the literal human readable value.

E.g. put it in your browsers dev console and output the result, and you'll see it's a non-issue:

[image]

As you can see, `’` was encoded as `\u2019O` because `20190` is the unicode character code of `’`, and HTML can't natively use those characters without some form of encoding. That's why when you inspect HTML, you'll see `&amp;` but when you view it in the browser you see `&`, the same thing is happening here

Comment: thank u for ur response but u can see we have the same with "title": "Avec l\u2019ONPA",  and with the "link" he add "#038;" after the "&" in the link

Comment: it'll be decoded at the other end, notice how it was double escaping, `\\ `  rather than `\ `, how are you testing it? Are you just looking at the output in the HTML? Or are you checking the value javascript gets? The values will be encoded entransit, so once you run it through `JSON.parse` those character codes will be turned into the real characters