# Rest API encoding of double quotes

Tags: rest-api, encoding

I have a standard rest API setup in WP. The results are displayed in an IOS App. Now the problem occurres, that single and double quotes and & are returned in the JSON as Unicode Decimal Code: eg. &#8216. All other characters seem fine.
Any Ideas to that?

Comment: How are you sending from WP to your iOS App? Did you see this response? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/303881/137650

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. The IOS App makes simple Rest API calls. Such as: http://somedomain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/news/7108. When I open the link in Firefox it displays the JSON formated in a readable way. And it also displays the &#8216 for a ' in a title.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show here an example of how you can convert the HTML to Plain Text in Swift 4.

This example simulate that you're receiving this:

WordPress&#8216House --> **WordPress'House**

1. Add this extension to convert your html code to a regular string:

`

```
extension Data {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: self, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error:", error)
            return  nil
        }
    }
    var html2String: String {
        return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}

extension String {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        return Data(utf8).html2AttributedString
    }
    var html2String: String {
        return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

2. Use the extension

`

```
let htmlString = "WordPress&#8216House"

print("String is: ", textFromWP.html2String)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this example. The App itself is beeing coded by another agency... They are not willing to decode in the front end. Hell...

Comment: it is your string passed through 'wp_json_encode' or without it?

Comment: Actually Idon't know. It is a setup of some plugins. ACF, ACF to REST API, Custom Post Type UI. It feels a bit of a Rabbit Hole to check for wp_json_encode.

Comment: Even when I start with a clean WP install. I get the same encoding in the JSON. Is there a way to alter the JSON output? Any Idea?

Comment: In this new WP install  are you using ACF to REST API?

Comment: I created a clean install of WP. No changes from my side. I save the first post with an ' in the title. The Rest API is showing a &#8216. For me it sounds like a it is build into WP like this and I have not found a way to change that behavior.

Comment: I created a clean install and test the plugin "WordPress REST API (Version 2)" and I also had the same result. For example Android's Architecture gave me the result: "Android&#8217;s architecture". The easiest way for me would be to decode in the front end.